# Why is my CSS menu sometimes mis-formatted?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website but are having a bit of a problem with the main menu.

Sometimes, maybe 1 in a 10 times, the menu doesn't load the way it is supposed to.

Take a look at the pictures below!

This is how the menu is supposed to look like: 
[image]

...and this is how the menu actually look like sometimes: 
[image]

```
ul.menu {
    font-size: 1.21em;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 29px;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
li.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
li:hover.menu { 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu"><a href="page_1.html" class="menu">PAGE 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="page_2.html" class="menu">PAGE 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="page_3.html" class="menu">PAGE 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your styles will never afftect your markup. the class in css is .menu and in your markup its top_menu. if that is just a failure from showing the code; the problem could be ul.menu float right; with not a given witdth. so you should set a min-width there.

Comment: Is it really required to add same class name on ul, li and a instead of adding classes on li and a they can be accessed in css via ul.menu li{}, ul.menu li a{} which is more robust and useful

Comment: `li:hover.menu {text-decoration: underline;}` is useless code because that is the default behavior of links anyway on hover. It should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your class in the HTML code is 'top_menu' but it's 'menu' in your CSS.
Moreover, you should add :

```
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
```

for the menu class, (because li is not inline by default)

and remove

```
float:left;
```

Comment: the menu element is floating right (li menu is floating left), display inline-block won't do anything

Comment: Yes, in fact. I sould have precise that. I will corect my answer

Comment: What do you expect `vertical-align: top;` to achieve? Because it doesn't achieve anything here.

Comment: Edit your answer to match the class in the OP's question, here is a fiddle of what you have http://jsfiddle.net/5Mm5m/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. Do you want your menu to be floating all the way to the right of the page? That is what your current `float:right/left;` properties are ultimately achieving.

If you don't want that, and/or if you want more precise control over styling of your menu items, you should **replace** `float: right;` and `float: left;` with `display: inline;` or `display:inline-block;` (both will accomplish the in-line style you're looking for, but the latter will have more padding on top and elsewhere).

Another problem is that your `li:hover.menu` selector code is entirely superfluous right now; `text-decoration: underline;` is the default behavior for links on hover already. To achieve what you want, which is `text-decoration: none;` on your links until you hover over them, you need to improve your selectors a bit. Right now, your `text-decoration: none;` property is applied to the `li` elements, but not their children (the `a` elements). I've fixed this as well in the CSS below.

My CSS:

```
ul.menu {
    font-size: 1.21em;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 29px;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
li.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

li.menu>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
}

li:hover.menu { 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDk47/)

Regardless, unless you set a fixed width for your menu div, your links are always going to fall in line vertically when the view-port is not wide enough to accommodate them all in-line.